# Whirlpool oven not beeping

Tags: oven

My whirlpool oven isn't beeping at all.  It is an electric  WFE505W0HS1 model.  The timer doesn't sound and neither when I press any buttons.  I've tried everything I could find on the web.  I cut the power supply and pressed a bunch of different sequences of buttons but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Contact Whirlpool. "*I cut the power supply and pressed a bunch of different sequences of buttons but nothing has worked so far."* Was there a method to this  madness?  Maybe leave the power on when you "press a bunch of different sequences of buttons". ;)

Comment: Buttons "work but don't beep" or "don't work at all"?

Comment: read the user nanual instead of pressing random buttons ... one of the settings may be "silent mode"

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is working, make sure you haven't activated the control lockout.  Hold the "control lock" button for 5 seconds and see if it changes.

While it's not mentioned in the manual for your model, other Whirlpool models have a silent mode that is toggled by holding the "COOK TIME" button for 5 seconds.  Try holding that one down to see if the sounds return.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that power is reaching the outlet the stove is plugged into. If you know this to be true check to see if any part of the stove is working. If it's an electric model do the heating elements work? Does the oven light work? If it's a gas model do the electric spark igniters work?

If you find that the stove is completely non-functional with no power at all and you confirmed that the outlet is energized the problem may be:

-the power cord could be broken. you will need to do a continuity test on each wire.

-the ovens plug may be damaged. Again test for continuity.

Sometimes the transformer on the stoves circuit board gets fried or expires. This transformer supplies the voltage for all the low voltage circuits on the stove (ie LED lights, signaling alarms and beeps and LCD read outs). For this repair you will need a technician to test the board.